# Is it possible to copy mysql Routines to another Database using Editor

Tags: mysql

I have two databases Local and Development.

I want to move Local Db's procedures to development Db but not all. I only want newly created procedures.

For that I am writing code. But I stuck. I have definition but i don't know how to execute it on another Database using SQL Editor(Workbench/Heidi SQL).

Consider below example:

```
SET @Proc_new_procedure = '
DELIMITER $$  

CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` (input1 varchar(50),input2 varchar(50))  
BEGIN 
SET input1 = LTRIM(input1);  
select * from table1 where column1 = input1; 
select * from table2 where column1 = input2; 
END$$ 
DELIMITER ; 
'; 

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @Proc_new_procedure; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

I got below error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near DELIMITER $$  CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` (input1 varchar(50),input2 varcha' at line 1

I tried Prepare statement to create procedure. But Prepare statement allow me only one statement execution at a time.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Yes, you need to use prepared statements or you need to manually run the extracted code. Pls show us what exactly you have tried and what error message or unexpected behaviour you encountered.

Comment: Hi, I added Code where i get an error message. Sorry for late response